# Excel VBA Passing Variables

Tags: excel, vba

[image: The data is monthly sales by Region]

I need to pass the variables max, min, and their respective locations to another sub where it will format each max and min in their respective column. I am trying to create an array that will store the locations and the values but its not working.

I was told to first identify the number of columns used and the number of rows, which is the beginning.

```
Rows = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Columns = wsData.UsedRange.Col.Count
    j = 1
    ReDim Min(j)
            
With wsData.Range("A3:A19")
For j = 1 To 19 'colum
    Min(j) = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(.Offset(1, j), .Offset(Row, j)))
    Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(.Offset(1, j), .Offset(Row, j)))
    
    Min(j) = Min
    j = j + 1
    ReDim Preserve Min(j) 'saves variables
Next 'next column
End With
```

Comment: I don't think you need `j = j + 1` if it's getting looped.

Comment: I want to increase the size of the array each time I add a variable

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation. You should size your array appropriately before looping, and avoid `ReDim Preserve` inside a loop.

Comment: You are not being clear in your description.  Please provide a set of data that a) shows what the input data looks like, b)shows what output you wish to get.  Please edit your post to provide this data as text so that we can copy it into our excel for testing purposes.

Comment: I would suggest watching the value of `j` in the locals window.  I think you may be skipping some columns with the way you are incrementing `j`

Comment: post has been edited. Hopefully this helps

Comment: You have a typo `Rows` vs. `Row`  Now is a good time to get into the habit of always putting `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module.

Comment: Please reedit your post to include the example as text that we can copy and paste into excel. You also need to provide an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses the `ActiveSheet` which you need to change to reference the worksheet for your data.  Additionally, it assumes that your data starts with **Row** 1.  The code looks at each column in the range and stores the minimum/maximum ***(it does not account for multiple cells which may share the min or max value)*** value found in the column as well as the cell's address, in an array and then passes the array to two different subs, one which simply displays the information in a message and one which formats the the background color of the cells.  This code does not perform any kind of error handling, but should get you where you want to go.

the line `Option Explicit` requires that all of the variables be defined using a `Dim` statement

the line `Option Base 1` makes the default starting point for arrays **1** instead of **0**

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub GatherData()
    Dim iRows As Long
    Dim iCols As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim iMin() As Variant
    Dim iMax() As Variant
    Dim R As Range
        iRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        iCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ReDim iMin(iCols, 2)
        ReDim iMax(iCols, 2)
        For j = 1 To iCols
            Set R = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j))), LookIn:=xlValues)
            iMin(j, 1) = R.Value
            iMin(j, 2) = R.Address
            Set R = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j))), LookIn:=xlValues)
            iMax(j, 1) = R.Value
            iMax(j, 2) = R.Address
        Next j
        ListMinMax iMax(), True
        ListMinMax iMin(), False
        FormatMinMax iMax, "green"
        FormatMinMax iMin, "yellow"
        Set R = Nothing
End Sub


Sub ListMinMax(ByRef Arr() As Variant, ByVal MinMax As Boolean)
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim i As Long
        If MinMax = True Then
            strOutput = "Maximums:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Else
            strOutput = "Minimums:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End If
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            strOutput = strOutput & "Cell: " & Arr(i, 2) & " = " & Arr(i, 1) & vbCrLf
        Next i
        MsgBox strOutput, vbOKOnly
End Sub

Sub FormatMinMax(ByRef Arr() As Variant, ByVal BGColor As String)
    Dim i As Long
        Select Case UCase(BGColor)
            Case "GREEN"
                For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
                    ActiveSheet.Range(Arr(i, 2)).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Next i
            Case "YELLOW"
                For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
                    ActiveSheet.Range(Arr(i, 2)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Next i
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Invalid Option", vbCritical
        End Select
End Sub
```

======================================================================

The code below does away with the need for the arrays and formats the color of the min/max values as it finds them

```
Sub GatherData2()
    Dim iRows As Long
    Dim iCols As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim R As Range
        iRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        iCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For j = 1 To iCols
            Set R = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j))), LookIn:=xlValues)
            R.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Set R = Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j)).Find(WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, j), Cells(iRows, j))), LookIn:=xlValues)
            R.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Next j
        Set R = Nothing
End Sub
```